# Does EMR support Hbase Replication

Tags: hbase, emr, amazon-emr

I am trying to test replication on two EMR cluster following the instructions mentioned here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/07/hbase-replication-overview-2/

I could run all the steps just fine but replication did not happen.  Amazon document is EXTREMELY UNCLEAR about whether they support replication or not with EMR.  Has anyone tried replication on EMR?  If yes do we need to modify any of the steps mentioned the document in the link.